# In which cases multiply and divide will not solve floating point errors?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, floating-point, runtime-error, precision

In the below snippet, the floating point error is solved by multiplying and dividing by a 10.

Without a multiply and divide the value of **z** comes up as `0.30000000000000004` instead of `0.3`.

The approach *"seems"* to be not ideal:

- It has extra overhead of computation for each digit.
- Extra computation will result in extra CPU consumption.

```js
var x = 0.1;
var y = 0.2;
var z = (x * 10 + y * 10) / 10;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

## Questions:

- Can a developer blindly use this for ALL cases where floating points are used?
- Are there any cases where this **multiply and divide** approach will not work for solving floating errors?

Comment: How does that solve anything? What exactly are you trying to solve anyway?

Comment: For floating point errors you can refer to the below link [Floating Point](http://modernweb.com/2014/02/17/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-floating-points/)

Comment: You'll have to accept that floating point has rounding errors. The fact you got the correct *output* does not mean a lot, You still have rounding errors, but they are so small they are not displayed. You were lucky.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Is `.toFixed` with `parseFloat` the best [work around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390608/in-which-cases-multiply-and-divide-will-not-solve-floating-point-errors?noredirect=1#comment56522886_34390697)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use `.toFixed` with some precision along with `parseFloat`.

```js
var x = 0.1;
var y = 0.2;

function add(foo, bar, precision){
    return parseFloat((foo + bar).toFixed(precision));
}

var sum = add(x, y, 1);
alert(sum);
```

Comment: This looks perfect with least code. Any suggestions about how does it **consume CPU**? Can I safely use it for **All** floating point uses?

Comment: What i would say is the CPU utilization will be almost same in both the cases, but this will be way more precise and accurate to use.

Comment: Yes @student even if you will do `var sum = add(x, y, 1000);` it will alert `.3`. So that's also a saviour.